.NET Maui Entry Control ReturnType Next Does not work
I have code that has numerous Entry controls with ReturnType=Next. This functionality does not work in Target .NET Runtime 8.0 but same code works with Target .NET Runtime 7.0 in Android. I have noticed other questions with regard to the same thing but the responses were not satisfactory. None of the topics addressed the Target .NET Runtime. Is there a work around other than recompiling solution with Target .NET Runtime 7.0?
Here is the code used:
<Entry Placeholder="Entry 1" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next"/>
<Entry Placeholder="Entry 2" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next"/>
<Entry Placeholder="Entry 3" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next"/>
<Entry Placeholder="Entry 4" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Done"/>




It would improve the question if you had comparative screenshots of 7.0 and 8.0.

I've added both versions of the same code based on 7.0 and 8.0. You will note that 7.0 allows you to go to next entry but 8.0 next does not work correctly.

With the screenshots the issue is more clear. Also worth posting the issue https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions for higher visibility with the dotnet maui devs.


Is there a work around other than recompiling solution with Target
.NET Runtime 7.0?

Yes, you can fix it by updating the input type using handlers:
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(EntryHandler), (handler, view) =>
{
#if ANDROID

          handler.PlatformView.UpdateReturnType(view);

#endif
});


Related issue link on Github: Softkeyboard Return key of an Entry control shows Done when the property ReturnType is set to Next #23086.

Your solution works great. My only question, is why is so easy to execute this code with .NET Runtime 7.0 and one has to add this additional code for .NET Runtime 8.0? Just curious.

@Shades49 It's related with the versions of Nuget packages: Microsoft.Maui.Controls and Microsoft.Maui.Control.Compatibility.  It works well in version: 8.0.40 both in .NET 7.0 and .NET 8.0. So, if you are using .NET 8.0, you can downgrade them to 8.0.40 without executing this additional code above. For more details, you can refer to my update link of the issue.
